# jquery hide ul element within parent ul of li

Tags: jquery, html, css

heres my code:

```
<ul class="table">      

<li class="dropdown">

    <a href="#" class="arrow">DROPDOWN ITEM</a>

</li>

<li class="hide">
<ul>

    <li class="row">THIS IS AN ITEM</li>    
    <li class="row">THIS IS ANOTHER ITEM</li>           

</ul>
</li>

</ul>

<ul class="table">      

<li class="dropdown">

    <a href="#" class="arrow">DROPDOWN ITEM</a>

</li>

<li class="hide">
<ul>

    <li class="row">THIS IS AN ITEM</li>    
    <li class="row">THIS IS ANOTHER ITEM</li>           

</ul>
</li>

</ul>
```

heres my jquery:

```
$('.arrow').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).parents('ul:eq(0)').find('.hide').is(":visible"))
        $(this).parents('ul:eq(0)').find('.hide').attr('display', 'none');
    else
        $(this).parents('ul:eq(0)').find('.hide').attr('display', 'block');         
});
```

you can see what i am trying to do, however its not working. when the "arrow" class is clicked, i want it to hide the "hide" class if it is not already hidden, if it is hidden then i want it to hide it. this should only apply to the parent UL so its only hiding the "hide" li within.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Display' isn't an attribute-- instead you want `css('display','none')`.

Comment: i got it to work using the hide() and show() functions. Thanks!